# How can I create two http security configurations with java based config?

Tags: java, spring-security

In XML config I could create the following:

```xml
<security:http pattern="/api/**"
               create-session="never"
               use-expressions="true">
  <security:http-basic entry-point-ref="xBasicAuthenticationEntryPoint"/>
  <security:session-management />
  <security:intercept-url pattern="/tests/**" access="isAuthenticated()"/>
  <security:intercept-url pattern="/api/**" access="isAuthenticated()"/>
</security:http>

<security:http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true" realm="ACME">
  <security:intercept-url pattern="/favicon.ico" access="permitAll" />
  <security:intercept-url pattern="/static/**" access="permitAll"/>
  <security:intercept-url pattern="/error/**" access="permitAll" />
  <security:intercept-url pattern="/" access="permitAll"/>
  <security:intercept-url pattern="/login" access="permitAll"/>
  <security:intercept-url pattern="/logout" access="isAuthenticated()"/>
  <security:form-login login-page='/login'
                       authentication-failure-url="/login?error"/>
  <security:logout logout-url="/logout" logout-success-url="/"/>
</security:http>
```

This would allow for all calls to `/api/**` to not try to authenticate the user if there is no session.

How do I create this same configuration with Java based config?

My `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter#configure(HttpSecurity)` method looks as follows:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.addFilter(switchUserFilter())
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/static/**").permitAll()
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and().formLogin()
              .loginPage("/login")
              .permitAll()
              .defaultSuccessUrl("/")
        .and().logout()
              .logoutUrl("/logout")
              .logoutSuccessUrl("/");
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well it is explicit in Spring Security Reference Manual, you put as many `@Configuration` annotated inner classes with an `@Order()` annotation to specify which are examined first. In your example it could look like :

```
@Order(1)
@Configuration
private static class ApiSecurityConfigurationAdapter
        extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .antMatcher("/api/**")
            .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.NEVER)
            .and.httpBasic().authenticationEntryPoint(xBasicAuthenticationEntryPoint)
            .and.authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().authenticated();
    }
}

@Configuration
private static class NormalSecurityConfigurationAdapter
        extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.addFilter(switchUserFilter())
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/static/**").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and().formLogin()
                  .loginPage("/login")
                  .permitAll()
                  .defaultSuccessUrl("/")
            .and().logout()
                  .logoutUrl("/logout")
                  .logoutSuccessUrl("/");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's correct, I don't know why I hadn't seen the answer but just after I posted I reexamined the docs and found the solution. Though I'm sure that wasn't there last time I looked, maybe new in 3.2.x? I was not sure how to register my `UserDetailsService` service, though have resorted to creating the bean externally, then autowiring into each configuration and overriding `userDetailsService()` in both to return the auto-wired bean which seems to be working, not sure if there's a simpler way though. Thanks